# Zend 1 plugin before set routing

Tags: php, zend-framework, plugins, radix

I need get plugin before load routes. I use `routeStartup` and `preDispatch` in plugin, but it doesn't help.

```
class Base_Controller_Plugin_Website extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeStartup(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request)
    {
        Base_Website::setRequest($request);
    }
}
```

I need method from `Base_Website`.

Comment: Something that needs to run before `routeStartup` might need to go in `Bootstrap`.

Comment: I found a `resources.frontController.dispatcher`, but i don't know, how to add a parameter `$request` (`Zend_Controller_Request_Http()`)

Answer (score 1):

The earliest front-controller plugin event is routeStartup, so if you want to perform some action prior to that, you'll need to do it in Bootstrap.

Unfortunately, the methods that run during bootstrap don't pass the Request and Response objects to you. You'll have to dig them out yourself. Something like:

```
class Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap
{
    // all your other _initXXX() bootstrap methods
    // etc...

    protected function _initSomethingUsingRequest()
    {
        $this->bootstrap('frontController');
        $front = $this->getResource('frontController');
        $request = $front->getRequest();

        // Now do whatever you want with your Request object
        // etc...
    }
}
```